# Latex \plus \times undefined in ACM template

Tags: acm, acmart

I am using an [ACM template](https://www.acm.org/publications/proceedings-template), and then I get the error **Undefined control sequence** for

```
\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart} 
\begin{document}
$(N[X],\plus,\times,0,1)$
\end{document}
```

I think it's caused by `\plus` and `\times` because after I removed them it works fine, but I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: as the error message clearly shows, `\plus` is not a defined command, use `+` (this isn;t related to ACM at all you would get the same error in most latex classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message on the supplied document is

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.3 $(N[X],\plus
                ,\times,0,1)$
? h
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

?
```

clearly showing that `\plus` is not defined. Use  `+` to get a plus sign. (You would get the same error in the standard classes, not just ACM)